# Extending IdentityRole

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I am currently developing MVC application I am using aspnet identity for the security.

I extend the `IdentityRole` class for future use.

Here is my code:

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public ApplicationRole()
        :base()
    { 
    }

    public ApplicationRole(string name)
        :base(name)
    {
    }
}
```

But when I try to create new instance of `ApplicationRole`, I get null

```
var role = new ApplicationRole(name);
//  I get null when I create a new Application Role
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this ...

Model :

```
 public class TenentUserRole : IdentityRole
    {
        [Required]
        public string TenantName { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
RoleManager<TenentUserRole> _roleManager = new RoleManager<TenentUserRole>(new RoleStore<TenantRole>(YOUR_DB_CONTEXT));
 _roleManager.Create(new TenentUserRole () { Name = role, TenantName = "TEMP"});
```